# What are the challenges for multilateral lender to increase the share of funding in local currencies?

Tags: finance, brics

> New Development Bank, the multilateral lender founded by the BRICS
> group of emerging-market countries, aims to increase the share of
> funding it raises in local currencies to 30% from less than 20%,
> according to its chief financial officer.
>
> “We will increase the use of local currencies,” CFO Leslie Maasdorp
> told Bloomberg on the sidelines of the BRICS meetings in Johannesburg
> on Wednesday. “It does not mean we are de-dollarizing or moving away
> from the dollar. It just means that we are raising more local-currency
> financing.”

https://www.bnnbloomberg.ca/brics-bank-aims-to-increase-local-currency-borrowing-to-30-1.1962533

What are the challenges for multilateral lender to increase the share of funding in local currencies? I heard that the NDB had trouble extending loans denominated in local currencies, but is there a specific reason why this is difficult. Is it more about political will or some technical details that makes this not easy, feasible or realistic at all?

Answer (score 3):

Lending in the "local currency" essentially means lending in a foreign currency in this context, which exposes the lender to the foreign currency risk, e.g. that they'd actually lose money on the loan it's a fixed rate one and there's unexpected inflation in the local currency. (The *expected* inflation would be factored into the loan's interest.)

This can be mitigated somewhat by variable rate loans (which track some central bank or similar authority interest rate, which hopefully keeps up with inflation), [automatic loan conversion](https://thedocs.worldbank.org/en/doc/06fa597117ada0801cc2cdcca0788623-0340012021/original/Local-Currency-Financing-Product-Note.pdf) [the latter means the loan is really calculated in some hard currency and only converted to the local currency as final step for each transaction/payment] etc., but those are more complex to manage for the lender.

Regarding variable-rate loans, the central bank of the country in question may be subject to local political pressures/control (a recent example that comes to mind [was](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/8/24/turkey-makes-bigger-than-expected-interest-rate-hike-targets-inflation) Turkey until not long ago), so it may or may not target inflation well.

There's also the issue of how the lender gets a hold of the local currency to lend. Typically this is [done](https://www.ifc.org/content/dam/ifc/doclink/2017/201710-ifc-local-currency-and-hedging-solutions.pdf) through currency swaps. For a large international lender these would be directly with the central bank issuing the local currency. Generally this is a non-issue, unless there are capital movement restrictions, which many developing countries do practice though.